# R木系(特に PR 木)のアルゴリズムを理解したい

Tags: アルゴリズム

位置情報などを効率的にインデックスするための手法として、R木があります。

## 質問

R木(特に、 PR 木)をどうやって実装するのか、とくに、そのアルゴリズムを知りたいと思っています。当たれる書籍などはありますか?